# Does there exists a smooth one-one map from $S^2 \to S^1$

Tags: differential-topology

While I was able to prove that there is no surjective, smooth map $f:S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$ but I am unable to prove this.

Suppose such a map exists, then by sard's theorem, it has a regular value. Hence there exists a unique $x \in S^2$ where $d_xf$ is surjective. But I am not able to proceed further. Any hint?

Comment: Such a map would violate Borsuk-Ulam after composing with the inclusion from the 1-sphere to the 2-sphere.

Comment: "There exists a *unique* $x \in S^{2} $ where $d_{x} f$ is surjective" is plain wrong. I think you misunderstand Sard. Anyway, i'd like to offer a possibly simpler solution than Randall's: f is a closed map since it's continuous between compact spaces, so if it's one to one it's an embedding of $S^{2}$ in $S^{1}$. If f is not onto this is a contradiction to the non-contractibility of $S^{2}$, and if f is onto it's a homeomorphism which is a contradiction to, say, $S^{2}$ being simply connected.